# How can i change the order in which my sprites are drawn in javascript canvas to create a 3D effekt

Tags: javascript, canvas

i have a little game in which the characters can move up, down, right and left and i want to make a realisic feeling of depth inside the game if that makes sense.

[the character in the red circle should be drawn first as long as he is above (behind) his enemy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjO6p.png)

i have this piece of code. the draw function will draw all the elements. i need the enemies and the character to be able to change their position in the draw function depending on their y position. enemies is an array of multiple objects which should be drawn individualy also depending on their y

thanks for helping a newbie <3

regards

```
draw() {
        this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

        this.ctx.translate(this.camera_x, 0);

        this.addObjectsToMap(this.level.background);
        this.addObjectsToMap(this.blood);
        this.addObjectsToMap(this.throwable);
        this.addObjectsToMap(this.level.enemies);
        this.addToMap(this.character);
        this.addObjectsToMap(this.level.blessings);
        this.addObjectsToMap(this.level.bombs);

        this.ctx.translate(-this.camera_x, 0); //fixed objects after this line

        //draw wird immer wieder aufgerufen. innerhalb der funktion funktioniert 'this' nicht.
        let self = this;
        requestAnimationFrame(function () {
            self.draw();
        });
    }

    addObjectsToMap(object) {
        object.forEach(o => {
            this.addToMap(o);
        });
    }

    addToMap(mo) {
        if (mo.otherDirection) {
            mo.mirrorSprite(this.ctx);
        }

        mo.draw(this.ctx);

        // mo.drawFrame(this.ctx);

        this.ctx.drawImage(mo.img, mo.x, mo.y, mo.width, mo.height);
        if (mo.otherDirection) {
            mo.mirrorSpriteBack(this.ctx);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i have found a solution in the meantime by myself:

every sprite got the feetY variable to provide offset for different size images.
i just put all objects in one array and sorted them by y.

```
draw() {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

    this.ctx.translate(this.camera_x, 0);

    this.addObjectsToMap(this.level.background);
    this.addObjectsToMap(this.blood);
    **this.addObjectsToMap(this.sortObjects());**

    this.ctx.translate(-this.camera_x, 0); //fixed objects after this line 

    //draw wird immer wieder aufgerufen. innerhalb der funktion funktioniert 'this' nicht.
    let self = this;
    requestAnimationFrame(function () {
        self.draw();
    });
}

/**
 * @returns sorted array of sprites so they will be drawn in correct order to create a 3D depth illusion
 */
sortObjects() {
    let sprites = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.level.enemies.length; i++) {
        sprites.push(this.level.enemies[i]);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < this.throwable.length; i++) {
        sprites.push(this.throwable[i]);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < this.level.blessings.length; i++) {
        sprites.push(this.level.blessings[i]);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < this.level.bombs.length; i++) {
        sprites.push(this.level.bombs[i]);
    }
    sprites.push(this.character);
    **sprites.sort((a, b) => (a.y + a.feetY) - (b.y + b.feetY));**
    return sprites;
}
```